# Notification Widget not opening every second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I've got some code online for a notification widget. I've tried to customize it by adding alerts from my database to display. I have no problems getting the information into the widget but for some reason I have two bugs which I cant seem to figure out.

Bug 1. Every second click on 'get data' will disable the notifcations from being hidden or shown

Bug 2. The number of notifications will go down when clicking the x button on the notifications, and it will go back up to 5 when you click get data. But as soon as you hit the x again, the counter will go back down to number of times the x has been clicked.

Recreate the bug: Click get data, remove a notification (click the x) -> down to 4, click get data -> back to 5, click X down to 3 when it should be down to 4. Now click get data, and x again, down to 2.

Code below + JS fiddle link

JS

```
var dataQueue = [];
var alertIds = [];
var items = [];

function addData(data){

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){


        if($.inArray(data[i].alertid, alertIds) == -1){
            // Id is not in the queue   
            dataQueue.push(data[i]);
            alertIds.push(data[i].alertid);
        }       
    }
    refreshNotifications();
}

function refreshNotifications() {


    for(i = items.length; i < 5; i++){
        items[i] = dataQueue.shift();
    }



    var cssTransitionEnd = getTransitionEnd();
    var container = $('div.alerts');

    // Remove old notification list
    $('div.notifications.js-notifications').remove();


    items.forEach(function(item) {   

        item.formattedDate = function() {     
            return this.date.getFullYear() + '-' +
                    strpad(this.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
                    strpad(this.date.getDate()) + " " + timeToString(this.date);      
        };
    }); 


    var template = 
      '<div class="notifications js-notifications">' +
        '<h3>Notifications</h3>' +
        '<ul class="notifications-list">' +
          '<li class="item no-data">You don\'t have notifications</li>' +
          '{{#items}}' +
            '<li class="item js-item" data-id="{{id}}">' +
              '<div class="details">' +
                '<span class="title">{{title}}</span>' +
                '<span class="date">{{formattedDate}}</span>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<button type="button" class="button-default button-dismiss js-dismiss">×</button>' +
            '</li>' +
          '{{/items}}' +
        '</ul>' +
        '<a href="#" class="show-all">Show all notifications</a>' +
      '</div>';

    container
        .append(Mustache.render(template, { items: items }))
        .find('.js-count').attr('data-count', items.length).html(items.length).end()
        .on('click', '.js-show-notifications', function(event) {
          $(event.currentTarget).closest('.js-show-notifications').toggleClass('active').blur();
          return true;
        })
        .on('click', '.js-dismiss', function(event) {
            var item = $(event.currentTarget).parents('.js-item');
            console.log("Item removed id: " + item.alertid);
            var removeItem = function() {
                item[0].removeEventListener(cssTransitionEnd, removeItem, false);
                item.remove();

                /* update notifications' counter */
                var countElement = container.find('.js-count');
                var prevCount = +countElement.attr('data-count');
                var newCount = prevCount - 1;
                countElement
                  .attr('data-count', newCount)
                  .html(newCount);

                if(newCount === 0) {
                  countElement.remove();
                  container.find('.js-notifications').addClass('empty');
                }
            };

            item[0].addEventListener(cssTransitionEnd, removeItem, false);
            item.addClass('dismissed');
            return true;
        });
}

function timeToString(date) {
    if (date) {
        var hh = date.getHours();
        var mm = date.getMinutes();
        var ap = hh >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

        hh = (hh >= 12) ? (hh - 12) : hh;
        hh = (hh === 0) ? 12 : hh;

        return (hh < 10 ? '0' : '') + hh.toString() + ':' +
        (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm.toString() + ' ' + ap;
    }
    return null;
}

function strpad(num) {
    if (parseInt(num) < 10) {
        return '0' + parseInt(num);
    } else {
        return parseInt(num);
    }
}

function getTransitionEnd() {
    var supportedStyles = window.document.createElement('fake').style;
    var properties = {
        'webkitTransition': { 'end': 'webkitTransitionEnd' },
        'oTransition': { 'end': 'oTransitionEnd' },
        'msTransition': { 'end': 'msTransitionEnd' },
        'transition': { 'end': 'transitionend' }
    };

var match = null;
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(properties).forEach(function(name) {
        if (!match && name in supportedStyles) {
            match = name;
            return;
        }
    });

    return (properties[match] || {}).end;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#get_db_data').click(function(){         

      var newData = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            var newDataArray = [];

          newDataArray.id = i + 1;  
          newDataArray.title = "IO ID " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
          newDataArray.date = new Date();
          newDataArray.alertid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);;
          newData[i] = newDataArray;
      }                 

            addData(newData);


    });
});

// mustache script would be below
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="button" id="get_db_data" value="Get Data" />
</div>
<div class="alerts">
  <button type="button" class="button-default show-notifications active js-show-notifications">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="30" height="32" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
      <defs>
        <g id="icon-bell">
          <path class="path1" d="M15.143 30.286q0-0.286-0.286-0.286-1.054 0-1.813-0.759t-0.759-1.813q0-0.286-0.286-0.286t-0.286 0.286q0 1.304 0.92 2.223t2.223 0.92q0.286 0 0.286-0.286zM3.268 25.143h23.179q-2.929-3.232-4.402-7.348t-1.473-8.652q0-4.571-5.714-4.571t-5.714 4.571q0 4.536-1.473 8.652t-4.402 7.348zM29.714 25.143q0 0.929-0.679 1.607t-1.607 0.679h-8q0 1.893-1.339 3.232t-3.232 1.339-3.232-1.339-1.339-3.232h-8q-0.929 0-1.607-0.679t-0.679-1.607q3.393-2.875 5.125-7.098t1.732-8.902q0-2.946 1.714-4.679t4.714-2.089q-0.143-0.321-0.143-0.661 0-0.714 0.5-1.214t1.214-0.5 1.214 0.5 0.5 1.214q0 0.339-0.143 0.661 3 0.357 4.714 2.089t1.714 4.679q0 4.679 1.732 8.902t5.125 7.098z"
          />
        </g>
      </defs>
      <g fill="#000000">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-bell" transform="translate(0 0)"></use>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="notifications-count js-count"></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
div .alerts {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.button-default {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  -o-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.show-notifications {
  position: relative;
}

.show-notifications:hover #icon-bell,
.show-notifications:focus #icon-bell,
.show-notifications.active #icon-bell {
  fill: #34495e;
}

.show-notifications #icon-bell {
  fill: #7f8c8d;
}

.show-notifications .notifications-count {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: #3498db;
  color: #fefefe;
  font: normal 0.85em 'Lato';
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 1.45em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -2px;
  width: 16px;
}

.show-notifications.active ~ .notifications {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100px;
}

.notifications {
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s opacity;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s opacity;
  -o-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s opacity;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s opacity;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -999px;
}

.notifications:after {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #3498db;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  width: 0;
}

.notifications h3,
.notifications .show-all {
  background: #3498db;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}

.notifications h3 {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.notifications .show-all {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.notifications .show-all:hover,
.notifications .show-all:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.notifications .notifications-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-out 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.25s ease-out 0.1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.25s ease-out 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out 0.1s;
  border-top: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
  color: #7f8c8d;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 350px;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item:before,
.notifications .notifications-list .item .details,
.notifications .notifications-list .item .button-dismiss {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item:before {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: #3498db;
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item .details {
  margin-left: 10px;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 280px;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item .details .title,
.notifications .notifications-list .item .details .date {
  display: block;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item .details .date {
  color: #95a5a6;
  font-size: .85em;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item .button-dismiss {
  color: #bdc3c7;
  font-size: 2.25em;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item .button-dismiss:hover,
.notifications .notifications-list .item .button-dismiss:focus {
  color: #95a5a6;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item.no-data {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item.no-data:before {
  display: none;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item.expired {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item.expired:before {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item.expired .details .date {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

.notifications .notifications-list .item.dismissed {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.notifications.empty .notifications-list .no-data {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sd7mrvza/2/

Comment: Can you not post Bug 1 and Bug 2 as separate questions? And pinpoint which bit of JavaScript is not functioning as you want it to.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Every time i hit get data it is adding the action listeners on top of each other. I thought the `.remove()` would remove the action listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured out the problem. I wasnt removing the events before re adding the items in the `div`.

```
.off('click', '.js-show-notifications')
.on('click', '.js-show-notifications', function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).closest('.js-show-notifications').toggleClass('active').blur();
    console.log("hide/unhide notifications");
    return true;
})
.off('click', '.js-dismiss')
.on('click', '.js-dismiss', function(event) {...}
```

Comment: Just figured it out too ;) - so the "removeItem" callback was called twice what explains the decrease of -2...

Comment: Yea same with the hide/unhide for the notification box, every 2 times it was clicked would cause the unhide/hide and every 3 was unhide/hide/unhide.